# Onchange is not working with Javascript entry

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with some dates to be filled in. I'm using Cold Fusion, but here am using just the form and input tags, not the "enhanced" CF tags. The user can select these dates only from a Javascript calendar.  The calendar works fine, the dates get filled in, the Javascript function "validx" is working, but the onchange does not fire with this data entry method.

```
<input 
  type     = "text" 
  id       = "#colid#"
  class    = "calendarSelectDate"  {this fires the calendar}             
  name     = "#col#" 
  readonly                         
  onclick  = "tooltip(#i#)"
  onchange = "validx(#i#, #top#, '#thecase#', '#themsg#')"
  value    = "#sv#" >
```

I can get onblur to do the job, but would really prefer onchange.  Anyone have a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are misunderstanding the purpose of `onchange`. This event fires when the user blurs the checkbox *after* making a change. By *definition* it requires a blur. Perhaps you should look into `onkeyup` or similar events involving keypresses.

Comment: okay, so I make a change using the Javascript calendar, and then create an onblur by going to the next data entry field.  The onchange is not firing.

Comment: That's probably because your JavaScript calendar is directly modifying the value of the textbox, which does not actually count as a change. It's just like calling the `click()` method of an object doesn't trigger the `onclick` event handler. I don't know what "JavaScript calendar" you're using, but it should have a custom event it fires when the user selects a date. Attach your `validx` function to that event. As an example, the jQuery UI datepicker has the `onselect` method: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Comment: Thank you.  You have explained it very well.  The js code does have an event listener, and I will try it that way.